# Angular7 - Issue in path location strategy

Tags: angular7

I'm working on the **Angular7** application where i'm using path location strategy instead of hash strategy.

So my application url should be like `http://www.example.com/application/users`

While my old url is: `http://www.example.com/application/#/users`

Now the problem is, when i hit the url nothing is loading but if useHash is true then everything is fine.

These steps i did:

- index.html - added   `<base href="/">`
- app-routing.module.ts - `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]`
- `build scripts: "build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot --deploy-url=/application/",`

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to use base href ="/application/" and try to build using this script ng build --prod --base-href=/application/